# How to animate water drop by geometry node?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I have created waterdrop on the monkey, but I do not know how to make water drop animation on the surface. It is similar to water drop from a icing coke bottle.

I tried to change seed of Distribute Points on Faces, but it only changes the location of waterdrop randomly. I want waterdrop following gravity.

My blender file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/K3W6ZYLN

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are going for. And not to answer the question, but I'd urge you to use particle systems instead for a simple rain effect.

Comment: @Benus why? Particle simulations require more computer power, GeoNodes can provide a quicker, simple result if accuracy is not an issue.

Comment: to be fair, there's a nice tutorial on raindrops animation using Material Nodes if you're interested https://youtu.be/ETld_S5QsSU

Comment: please check an answer as correct (click on checkmark left to the answer) if it helped you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setup creates droplets on cylindrical surface. I'm not sure how to do on other surfaces. May be using ray cast node you can project this on different surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: However, using raycast will not make the speed of the droplet realistic (depending on the topology it might look quite wrong). And since goemetry nodes are "stateless" in the sense they are run independently and don't communicate between frames. This is why a simulation is probably better, but your solution, I think, is as good as it get in geonodes.