Geometry Node not working
So, I've recently installed Blender 4.2 and geometry nodes aren't working. I don't know much in geometry nodes or how to use them so maybe if someone can help me add water droplets on my can.

Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250072/how-to-animate-water-drop-by-geometry-node. If not, there are several YT tutorials online if you can be bothered to search for them!

You will find a Blender file about such a thing in this post : Intersecting Droplets.

May I suggest to improve the title of your question, because 1) GN are most probably working ; 2) the subject is about modelling droplets ?
